# How to read all xml nodes for respective Attribute values using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to execute different set of xml nodes which are being identified by their respective attributes values in xml.
But what i am facing is that only the set 1 xml nodes are getting executed even the second attribute value is being identified.Here is my current code:

```
for (int m = 0; m < 10; m++)
{
    attrVal_New = Update_Bugs[m].Attributes["TestCondition"].Value;
    foreach (string attr in attrVal_New.Split(','))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(attr);
        ....
```

Please find the sample xml as follows:

```
<DrWatson>
  <Bugs Name="Testing 11" TestCondition="STATE">
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
    <Bug>
          <family>ESG</family>
          <product>Dr.Watson</product>
          <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
          <note></note>
    </Bug>
  </Bugs>
  <Bugs Name="Testing 22" TestCondition="STATUS">
    <Bug>
          <family>ESG</family>
          <product>Dr.Watson</product>
          <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
          <note></note>
    </Bug>
    <Bug>
    <family>ESG</family>
          <product>Dr.Watson</product>
          <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
          <note></note>
    </Bug>
  </Bugs>
</DrWatson>
```

Please note that there are different attribute value defined under TestCondition as 'STATE' and STATUS. when running this loop second time the attribute value is being detected as `'STATUS'` but it executes the xml nodes which are present under `'STATE'` attribute value.Please suggest.

Here is the code snippet for 'Update Bugs' as follows:

```
 XmlDocument XDoc = new DrWatsonCore().LoadXMLFromFile(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_BugAdd_CreateBugs_DataFile);
                XmlNodeList Update_Bugs = XDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Bugs");
```

i am using this part to identify the `Attribute Tag Names` in the xml available under `'TestCondition'` in my xml.

This is what i am doing after your suggestion and i am facing the same issue again as i am picking up the second attribute value but the set of xml nodes available under `STATE` attribute value is getting executed.

```
for (int m = 0; m < 10; m++)
                {
                    XmlAttributeCollection coll = Update_Bugs.Item(m).Attributes;
                    string value = coll.Item(m).Value;
                attrVal_New = Update_Bugs[m].Attributes["TestCondition"].Value;

                //m++;
                foreach (string attr in attrVal_New.Split(','))
                {                        

                        string attributelowercase = attr.ToLower();                        
                        //Step1: Create Bugs
                        List<string> BugWSResponseList1 = new List<string>();                        
                        BugWSResponseList1 = CreateBugs(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_BugAdd_CreateBugs_DataFile, newValue);
```

Comment: It would be useful to show type and code used to obtain `Update_Bugs` object.

Comment: I've edited your sample and removed everything that either commented out or not using `Update_Bugs` - it looks like you did not post portion of the code that should be using `Update_Bugs[m]` node...

Comment: Update_Bugs is XMLNode?

Comment: @ Alexei Levenkov Please find my updated code with the code snippet for 'Update_Bugs'

Comment: @Vikram Bose yes thats right.. Update_Bugs is the xml node identified on the basis of Attribute Value Tag Name under 'TestCondition' within xml.

Comment: @user2778482 : See my answer below if any doubt u can ask...

Comment: Where and how do you do the test on the attribute value for "TestCondidition"?

Comment: coll.Item(1).Value is the TestCondition

Comment: @VikramBose Please find my updated code snippet after using your workaround.

Comment: @VikramBose Actually after identifying the xml nodes on the basis of Attribute Values i need to create some data using the <Bug><Bug> nodes available in the respective Attributes within xml.I am able to change the attributes using your workaround but the set of <Bug><Bug> is being executed for the first Attribute only.

Comment: @Marco Any suggestions from your side.

Comment: @user2778482 : I am getting both state and status see my answer below.

Comment: @VikramBose Yes even i am getting both the attributes but what i want is to read the respective <Bug><Bug> nodes for each attribute value.

Comment: nodeList.Item(0).ChildNodes.Item(0).ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText

Comment: here you are getting the inner values

Comment: See my answer below... I changed the Product Name.

Comment: @VikramBose I dont want the inner text but i want to fetch the Bug to Bug xml nodes for attributes value 'STATE' and 'STATUS' respectively as i would be creating some data using these <Bug> nodes.

Answer (score 1):

```
    foreach (XmlElement xmlElement in nodeList)
            {
                foreach (XmlElement xmlElement1 in xmlElement.ChildNodes)
                {
                    foreach (XmlElement xmlElement2 in xmlElement1.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        string value = xmlElement2.InnerText;
                        Debug.WriteLine(value);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Output :

```
ESG
Dr.Vatson
Blank

ESG
Dr.Hello
Blank

ESG
Dr.Vikram
Blank

ESG
Dr.Watson
Blank
```

Comment: Please find my updated code snippet after using your workaround.

Comment: My Mis.. Please find the updated code i am using for trying your workaround

Answer (score 0):

I do not knwo why tou have a for loop or why you have the split on the attribute value, but I would write the code like this

```
//Get all the bugs.
XmlNodeList Update_Bugs = XDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Bugs");

//Loop through the bugs
foreach(XmlNode updateBug in Update_Bugs)
{
    //Check for the test condition
    if (updateBug.Attributes["TestCondition"] != null)
    {
        //Get the value of TestCondition.
        string value = updateBug.Attributes["TestCondition"].Value;
        string attributelowercase = value.ToLower();
        Console.WriteLine(attributelowercase);
        //Get the children of the node. This will be the <Bug> nodes.
        XmlNodeList newValue = updateBug.ChildNodes;
        //Get the xml string of the bugs
        string xmlString = updateBug.InnerXml;
        Console.WriteLine(xmlString);
    }
}
```

This will give you as output the TestCondotion and the XML between the  tags e.g.:

```
<Bug>
  <family>ESG</family>
  <product>Dr.Watson</product>
  <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
  <note></note>
</Bug>
<Bug>
  <family>ESG</family>
  <product>Dr.Watson</product>
  <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
  <note></note>
</Bug>
```

How to process this depends on wht you want do do with it.

Comment: How can i get the newvalue response as xml document not as string.Please suggest.